# How to center my article list div tag?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi I'm building a wordpress site and I'm looking how to center the tag "articles-list" here: http://www.containerfr8.com.au/blog/

I've tried a few things like setting margin left/right to auto etc but no effect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Code. provide the code and someone will be glad to help you.

Comment: It's from a wordpress site so it's a bit harder than that, figured inspecting element through browser would be easier as there's a lot of parents etc

Comment: Point us in the right direction then, where its located, where to click.

Comment: Hit the blog post and get it so you see the tag article-list. I want all articles centered.

Comment: @josi it is centred for me on Chrome.

Comment: It's been solved now.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really hard for us to help you with a question where you point us at a site. It's often better to include images eg "this is what I see" and "this is what i expect to see" - and also the code -> you say to right click and inspect in the browser... but you could do that and then copy what you get into your question next time :)

Comment: Also - we kinda frown on questions that link to external sites for detail because links can go stale and we want stack overflow questions to be eternal - somebody else will probably have the same problem as you and the answers here could help them too. But to do that, your question needs to contain all the elements required to identify the problem.  I know it's harder for a question like this - but we'd really like you to try. So can you please do that now for the sake of future newbies who need help (just like you did)? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is so broad and does not contain any code I will provide a broad answer which does not contain any code.

[Center everything guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)